# How do I arrange these objects in an arraylist

Tags: java, oop, javafx

I've been given an assignment to create an arena of objects that move, rotate and collide in JavaFX. My lecturer has instructed us to use a List for all objects that will appear in the game. All objects inherit from an abstract class with abstract methods for calculating position and rotation ect.
Each object can also have attachments, for instance a 'whisker' that detects other objects and turns the robot accordingly.

```
public class Robot extends Object{
private double energy;
private ArrayList<Object> attachments = new ArrayList<Object>();

public class Whisker extends Object{
private Object attached;
private Line whisker;
```

Should each robot have an arraylist of 'attachments' that are connected to the robot?

Each attachment would also need to know which robot it is connected to.

Will this cause issues? or will this effectively create a double linked between objects and attachments?

or should all objects have their own array lists?

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't extends your classes in the way you did. Let me put this way - every instance of any class "extends" Object class. I mean every object IS Object. Second, you should provide an interface class (as the "contract" what EVERY of your Robot can or cannot do)

Comment: Your question is very broad, but I'd expect a `Robot` to _have a_ `Whisker`, as well as energy, position and rotation. If a `Robot` has more than one `Whisker`, I'd expect it to _have a_ `List< Whisker>`. I'd expect a `List<Attachment>` only if attachments have something in common.